# JQuery to change price based on selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select

Struggling with the script that would grab a price and add to it if an option is selected. The code I'm using:

```js
var basePrice = +($('#price').html());;

$(".readers").change(function() {
  newPrice = basePrice;
  $(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += $(this).data('#price')
  });
  $("#price").html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<span class="product-price" itemprop="price" id="price">$299.00</span>
<label>Magnification</label>
<select class="product-variants readers" id="readers" name="readers">
           <option data-price="0" value="0">None</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="+1.50">+1.50</option>
     <option data-price="40" value="+2.00">+2.00</option>                   
    <option data-price="40" value="+2.50">+2.50</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for any cross-posting: I've seen related threads, yet can't figure out what the problem in my case is.

Any help is much appreciated!

~N.

Comment: +"$299.00" will be converted to NaN

Comment: `$(this).data('#price')` is incorrect. You don't have a `data-#price` attribute on your elements and I don't think it would even work. use `.data('price')`.

Comment: What kind of response do you get from your code? It seems your values are strings not numbers!

Answer (score 0):

You're not parsing the value in `#price` appropriately. You should be removing invalid characters, such as commas and dollar signs, or any non-numeric/period character, and then convert it to a numeric variable, such as here:

```
var basePrice = +($('#price').html()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");

$(".readers").change(function() {
  newPrice = basePrice;
  $(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += $(this).attr("data-price");
  });
  $("#price").html("$"+newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

It would be less expensive if you just removed the dollar sign and any other invalid characters from the HTML to begin with, however, and then you don't have to use regex to pull invalid characters.

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LshhgoLf/1/) for your enjoyment.

And a snippet because, why not?

```js
var basePrice = +($('#price').html()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
$(".readers").change(function() {
  newPrice = basePrice;
  $(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price')
  });
  $("#price").html("$" + newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="product-price" itemprop="price" id="price">$299.00</span>
<label>Magnification</label>
<select class="product-variants readers" id="readers" name="readers">
           <option data-price="0" value="0">None</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="+1.50">+1.50</option>
     <option data-price="40" value="+2.00">+2.00</option>                   
    <option data-price="40" value="+2.50">+2.50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you even test it?

Comment: I've tested your code in the code snippet and it throws an error, actually. Provide jsfiddle link in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied the code from the answer and added the regex. Then, a couple seconds after, realized that I forgot to change to check the `data-price` attribute instead of what the questioner was doing. I had changed it in my fiddle just didn't copy it from there. :/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NaN` because the `innerHTML` attribute of the `#price` element is a string (it contains a `$` sign).

```js
var basePrice = +($('#price').html().match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]);

$(".readers").change(function() {
  newPrice = basePrice;
  $(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price');
  });
  $("#price").html('$' + newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="product-price" itemprop="price" id="price">$299.00</span>
<label>Magnification</label>
<select class="product-variants readers" id="readers" name="readers">
           <option data-price="0" value="0">None</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="+1.50">+1.50</option>
     <option data-price="40" value="+2.00">+2.00</option>                   
    <option data-price="40" value="+2.50">+2.50</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) you can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in order to get the text value of 
span tag.

Because your text contains the dollar sign you can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for getting the number and add the plus sign to convert it:

```
+$('#price').text().match(/[\d.]+/)[0]
```

It's useless to have a global variable because you can compute the new value on the fly:

```
var newPrice = +$('#price').text().split('$')[1] + +$(".readers option:selected").data('price');
```

Because your select tag is not a multiselect you can avoid the loop:

```
$(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
```

Don't add the # sign in the data function.

Finally you can use a regex pattern to change the span text value:

```
txt.replace(/[\d.]+/, newPrice.toFixed(2));
```

The example:

```js
$(".readers").change(function() {
  var newPrice = +$('#price').text().split('$')[1] + +$(".readers option:selected").data('price');
  $('#price').text(function(i, txt) {
      return txt.replace(/[\d.]+/, newPrice.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="product-price" itemprop="price" id="price">$299.00</span>
<label>Magnification</label>
<select class="product-variants readers" id="readers" name="readers">
    <option data-price="0" value="0">None</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="+1.50">+1.50</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="+2.00">+2.00</option>
    <option data-price="40" value="+2.50">+2.50</option>
</select>
```